# Regular expression capturing groups

Tags: c#, regex, expression, capturing-group

With the following regular expression:

```
InitValue\((\w*)\)
```

and the test string:

```
InitValue(Input1)
```

I get the following result:

```
Full match: InitValue(Input1)
Group1: Input1
```

With the following regular expression:

```
InitValue\((\w*)\s*,\s*(\w*)\)
```

and the test string:

```
InitValue(Input1, Input2)
```

I get:

```
Full match: InitValue(Input1, Input2)
Group1: Input1
Group2: Input2
```

Now I would like to capture any number of arguments to the InitValue-method. The number of arguments to InitValue are unknown.

```
Full match: InitValue(Input1, Input2, ..., Inputn)
Group1: Input1
Group2: Input2
....
Groupn: Inputn
```

Of course I can't repeat the following pattern in my regular expression since I don't know the number of arguments in advance:

```
\s*,\s*(\w*)
```

How do I write a regular expression which outputs n number of capture groups?

I use the regular expression in C#-code (Regex, Match)...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this in .NET - you use a single capture `Group`, and then you access the Group's `Captures` collection to see all the items it captured, not just the final `Value`.

You'll have to write a regex that can repeat the argument-matching group, something like

```
InitValue\((?:(\w+)\s*(?:,(?!\s*\))|(?=\s*\)))\s*)*\)
```

Have a play around with the [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VIXEDH9H63C2HWc1) to get it to match what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void GetParams()
{
    int x = 0;
    var strings = new[]
    {
        "InitValue()",
        "InitValue(Input1)",
        "InitValue(Input1, Input2, Input3, Input4)"
    };

    var pattern = @"(\w+)\((?:(\w+)(?:,?\s*))*\)";

    foreach (var s in strings)
    {
        WriteLine($"String: '{s}'");
        var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            WriteLine($"\tMethod: '{match.Groups[1].Value}'");
            WriteLine("\tParameters:");
            var captures = match.Groups[2].Captures;
            if (captures.Count > 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                foreach (Capture capture in captures)
                {
                    WriteLine($"\t\tParam {++x}: '{capture.Value}'");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                WriteLine("\t\tNo params found.");
            }

            WriteLine();
        }

        else
            WriteLine("No matches found.");
    }
}

/*
Output:

String: 'InitValue()'
        Method: 'InitValue'
        Parameters:
                No params found.

String: 'InitValue(Input1)'
        Method: 'InitValue'
        Parameters:
                Param 1: 'Input1'

String: 'InitValue(Input1, Input2, Input3, Input4)'
        Method: 'InitValue'
        Parameters:
                Param 1: 'Input1'
                Param 2: 'Input2'
                Param 3: 'Input3'
                Param 4: 'Input4'
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET supports infinite lookbehind `(?<=`. Instead of getting capturing groups, another option could be to get the matches instead:

```
(?<=\bInitValue\([^()]*)[^, ]+(?=[^()]*\))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, check what is on the left matches:

  - `\bInitValue\([^()]*` Match wordboundary, `InitValue(` and then 0+ times not any of `(` or `)`
- `)` Close positive lookbehind
- `[^, \t]+` Negative character class, match 1+ times not a space or comma
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to check what is on the right matches:

  - `[^()]*\)` Match 0+ times not any of `(` or `)`, then match `)`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

For example:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\bInitValue\([^()]*)[^, ]+(?=[^()]*\))";
string str = "InitValue(Input1, Input2, Input3)";            
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(str, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Result

```
Input1
Input2
Input3
```

See the [Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbInitValue%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%29%5b%5e%2c+%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%29&i=InitValue%28Input1%2c+Input2%2c+Input3%29) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/KKG4cX)

Answer (score 0):

Don't let anyone tells you what it's impossible and what it's not

[image]

You will have to touch it a little bit but I think it can guide you =D.

Edit, answering your question. `b.Count` will give you the number of matchings.
Edit 2, I post the picture to show the debug info. But here is the code for the sibarist.

```
string bar = "test, othertest";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[\w]+");

MatchCollection b = reg.Matches(bar);

string b1 = b[0].Value;
string b2 = b[1].Value;

int numberGroups = b.Count;
```

Edit 3, as suggested in the comment this is the complete solution, you will need to clear the *InitValue(*)* part with another `Regex` or with a `Substring`

```
string input = "InitValue(test, othertest, bleh, blehTest, foo)";

Regex regArgs = new Regex(@"(?:InitValue\()(.*)(?:\))");
Match matchArgs = regArgs.Match(input);

string valueArgs = matchArgs.Groups[1].Value;

Regex reg = new Regex(@"[\w]+");

MatchCollection b = reg.Matches(valueArgs);

string b1 = b[0].Value;
string b2 = b[1].Value;

int numberGroups = b.Count;
```

Comment: Please, show how do you apply this technique to the test string: `InitValue(Input1, Input2, Input3, Input4)`

Comment: What do you mean? As I said, this is only ilustrative, not the full solution, but close enough. You can easily delete the `InitValue(*)` with a `Substring`and keep the arguments, if you mean that it is impossible when it's written InitValue, then yes, you are right, but that's far from being impossible =D